# Emacs: how to improve code, remapping $ and \

Tags: emacs, elisp

In php programming I use "$" key quite a lot - it's put at the beginning of every variable. And "\" is not used frequntly. But to get "$" symbol I need to press 2 keys: `Shift` - 4. While for `\` only 1. So I created the following code, remapping these keys:

```
(defun add-slash ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "\\")
  )

(defun add-dollar ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "$")
  )

(defun my-php-mode ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "$") 'add-slash)
  (local-set-key (kbd "\\") 'add-dollar)
)

(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'my-php-mode)
```

It works, but I feel like it can be improved. Suppose, we had a function: `remap-keys (key1 key2)`. In this case all this code could be written like this:

```
(defun my-php-mode ()
  (remap-keys (kbd "$") (kbd "\\"))
)

(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'my-php-mode)
```

Any suggestions, how to improve the code, using a function like `remap-keys`?

Comment: To be terrible honest: I would not ever swap ?$ and ?\\. If this is for a single mode only you will definitively misstype the letters from time to time. Furthermore, if you need somebody else to type something on your keyboard he will be very confused. Concerning your question: 1st: I am not aware of a command like `remap-keys`. 2nd: I would not litter the global namespace with functions like `add-slash`. Use lambdas instead in the hook. Note, that lambdas can also be `interactive`.

Comment: @Tobias Lambdas is a good idea. Yes, I want it only for programming languages with frequent usage of `$` symbol: PHP, Perl and javascript with JQuery lib activated. I am the only person, using the machine. So, my remapping won't hurt anyone.

Comment: @Tobias What do you think about key-translation-map: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_key-translation-map.html? But it seems to be the global remap.

Comment: Yes it is global and therefore I would not fiddle around with it -- even not with commands like `make-variable-buffer-local` or `make-local-variable`. If you really want to remap those keys and you have working code just use it. If you need this remapping for multiple modes you could write a (small) minor-mode for it and put the remapping into the minor-mode's keymap. This will override the major-mode's keymap. The code segment is so small that it does no large impact on performance or readability. Therefore, thinking about optimization of that code segment is not worth the money.